# Punctuation and parenthesis

Tags: parentheses

Just saw this. Shouldn't it have the period (full-stop) after the parenthesis?

> Like the magazine? Take it with you. (Don’t worry, we’ll give the next passenger a new copy)

Comment: I've heard it claimed before that the closing bracket doubles as a full stop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a good idea to end sentences with either "."  "!", or "?".

In addition, it's a good idea to start sentences with a capitalized letter. It's also a good idea to separate independent clause with ";".

In your example, the parenthetical remark is a complete separate sentence, so I would be inclined to put the "." *inside* the ending parenthesis:

- (Don't worry; we'll give the next passenger a new copy.)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your comments, I was also interested by the fact that it's a complete clause in parenthesis, existing on its own after the previous period.

Comment: It's two clauses, constituting a whole sentence. That's why I inserted both a semicolon and a period.